# How to understand why Google Chrome suddenly stops/crashes?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, crash, macos-monterey

At a frequency ranging from once every 4 days to a couple times a day, the Google Chrome window disappears.

Chrome does not hang. The window just disappears and is also no longer visible from in the dock. When I restart Chrome, it asks if I want to restore pages and is able to do so.

This happens whether start it by navigating to Applications > Google Chrome or on the terminal by running

```
nohup /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --enable-logging --v=1 --profile-directory='Default'
```

After a crash, I'm not able to see anything suspicious in the final 300 lines of

```
/Users/andrewfarrell/Library/Application\ Support/Google/Chrome/chrome_debug.log
```

However, I do not know what to look for in particular. What would be the next step to debug this?

---

Chrome Version 100.0.4896.127 (Official Build) (arm64)

OSX Version 12.3.1 on the Apple M1 Max Chip.

Answer (score 1):

*From comments [now deleted]*
Re-installing a Mac app is usually a complete waste of time, as the exact same thing is put back in the exact same place. If an app is actually corrupted, the OS won't let it run.

Cleaning out the cache, prefs, extensions, however is not a waste of time.
If you want to do this easily, then drop the app on [AppCleaner](https://freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/) (Freeware) then uncheck the app itself from the deletion list before applying. Next run you'll have a totally clean Chrome.

This, of course, preserves no user data. If you want to be selective as to what is deleted, use the folder paths provided by AppCleaner to hand-pick what to lose, what to keep. Alternatively, move everything out to a safe place you can copy back from.